# I lose information about user when refreshing page? Angular 2+ NgRx store

Tags: angular, store, ngrx

I need to post user info but I am losing it to refresh. How to set up 
isAuthenticated variable that we do not lose value on refresh?
Maybe you don't need to look at most of this code just to tell me how to fix it now
Piece of my code which you need:

Component:

```
  getState: Observable<any>;
  isAuthenticated: false;
  user = null;
  errorMessage = null;
  globalisAuthenticated = null;
  constructor(public dialog: MatDialog, private store: Store<AppState>) {
    this.getState = this.store.select(selectAuthState);
   }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.getState.subscribe((state) => {
      this.isAuthenticated = state.isAuthenticated;
      this.user = state.user;
      this.errorMessage = state.errorMessage;
      // console.log("is" , this.isAuthenticated)
      localStorage.setItem("isAuthenticated", state.isAuthenticated);
    });
```

Reducer:

```
export interface State {
  // is a user authenticated?
  isAuthenticated: boolean;
  // if authenticated, there should be a user object
  user: User | null;
  // error message
  errorMessage: string | null;
}

export const initialState: State = {
  isAuthenticated: false,
  user: null,
  errorMessage: null
};

    export function reducer(state = initialState, action: All): State {
      switch (action.type) {
        case AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS: {
          return {
            ...state,
            isAuthenticated: true,
            user: {
              token: action.payload.token,
              email: action.payload.email
            },
            errorMessage: null
          };
        }
        case AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_FAILURE: {
          return {
            ...state,
            errorMessage: 'Incorrect email and/or password.'
          };
        }
        default: {
          return state;
        }
      }
    }
```

Effect:

```
  @Effect()
LogIn: Observable<any> = this.actions
  .ofType(AuthActionTypes.LOGIN)
  .map((action: LogIn) => action.payload)
  .switchMap(payload => {
    return this.authService.logIn(payload.email, payload.password)
      .map((user) => {
        console.log(user);
        return new LogInSuccess({token: user.token, email: payload.email});
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        return Observable.of(new LogInFailure({ error: error }));
      });
  });

  @Effect({ dispatch: false })
LogInSuccess: Observable<any> = this.actions.pipe(
  ofType(AuthActionTypes.LOGIN_SUCCESS),
  tap((user) => {
    console.log("User",  user);
    localStorage.setItem('token', user.payload.token);
    this.snackBar.open("Uspesno ste ste prijavili.", null, {
      duration: 5000,
      verticalPosition: 'bottom',
      horizontalPosition: 'right'
   });
  })
);
```

State:

```
export interface AppState {
  authState: auth.State;
}

export const reducers = {
  auth: auth.reducer
};

export const selectAuthState = createFeatureSelector<AppState>('auth');
```

Can you tell me a way to avoid losing data on refresh?
if you need more information just ask me. 
This is doing all right for now. But when I do refresh I lose everything but the token is here in localstorage.

UPDATE UPDATE UPDATE
I am added this but again no work

```
  import { StoreModule, ActionReducerMap, ActionReducer, MetaReducer } from '@ngrx/store';
  import { localStorageSync } from 'ngrx-store-localstorage';
  import { reducers } from './reducers';


  // const reducers: ActionReducerMap<IState> = {todos, visibilityFilter};

  export function localStorageSyncReducer(reducer: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any> {
    return localStorageSync({keys: ['todos']})(reducer);
  }
  const metaReducers: Array<MetaReducer<any, any>> = [localStorageSyncReducer];
```

Comment: You have to add the `metaReducers` to your `StoreModule`, like this:

`StoreModule.forRoot(reducers, {
            metaReducers, ... }`

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that you lose state on refresh. You will need to persist the state yourself or use a library such as https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngrx-store-localstorage .

Comment: Do you have any tutorial on how to implement this package? I am new in angular

Comment: @AleksandarMihailovic: I don't, but the instructions in the package are straightforward and include sample code.

Comment: Did you using package ? I copy/paste example of code but again no work. Look update answear.

Comment: Did you add it to the current module and register the metaReducers like in the example? It is not clear from your description where you added the code.

Comment: Look my image 
https://ibb.co/7K93yLh

But I also have one reduce before this from my state
import { reducers } from './store/app.states';

This is module.app file
@cisse

Comment: You need to specify the state keys you would like to save in the localStorageSync function, not just literally take over the example.

Comment: I want to save isAuthentificated and user ?
How to that?
How?

Comment: Please read the documentation, you need to specify the keys you want to persist. From what I can see it is probably:
<code>
    export function localStorageSyncReducer(reducer: ActionReducer<any>):    ActionReducer<any> {
    return localStorageSync({keys: ['auth']})(reducer);
    }
</code>

Comment: that's what it looks like yes. You need to specify the correct keys to persist. I understand isAuthenticated and user are stored under 'auth' in the store.

Comment: Can you tell me what is keys: ['auth'] data? 
I don't know location that data? 
What is keys?
what is auth? 
My variable or what? 
From location come this?

Comment: In your original question, you shared about State:
```
export const selectAuthState = createFeatureSelector<AppState>('auth');
```
What is meant with 'key' is the property name for your authorisation state from the root State.

Answer (score 0):

you can save this value to localStorage of the browser as :

```
localStorage.setItem("auth", JSON.stringify(this.isAuthentificated));
```

then, when you access the app, get the value.

```
this.isAuthentificated = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("auth"));
```

But, when you log out, you need to set the value false on localStorage, or to delete the key. (I prefer the first one)

1) `localStorage.removeItem("auth");`
or

2) `localStorage.setItem("auth", false);`

Comment: Did I can store my boolean variable isAuthentificated ?

Comment: yes, you can store it, but you need to update or create/delete it at login/logout

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
  export function localStorageSyncReducer(reducer: ActionReducer<any>): ActionReducer<any> {
     return localStorageSync( {keys: ['auth'], rehydrate: true})(reducer);
  }
```

Comment: can you tell me what is exactly keys? What is auth? From location this data coming ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is what you should expect from NgRx.  You will need to re-fetch the user each time the browser is refreshed.  There are multiple ways of doing this.  I use JWT authentication, so the state update process looks something like this:

1. User logs in by typing username and password
2. Angular authenticates the user successfully and saves the issued JWT to `localStorage`.
3. User refreshes page, which causes state to be lost.  That is not a problem, because in the Component's `ngOnInit()` hook, your code should check for the JWT token.  If it doesn't find a JWT in local storage, it immediately sets the authentication state to "logged out".  If it does find a JWT token, it dispatches a new action, which we will call `GET_USER`.
4. The `GET_USER` action will have a single effect.  This effect will send out an API GET request to your `/api/user` route.

At this point, you're probably wondering two things.  First, you might wonder what the purpose of a GET request is?  Well, the GET request will not work immediately.  Obviously, you will need some sort of HTTP Header to send along with the GET request so that the backend can figure out which user you are trying to get.  To do this, you can set up an [HttpInterceptor](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpInterceptor).  This interceptor will intercept every outgoing HTTP request and attach the JWT token that is stored in `localStorage`.

Secondly, you might wonder how the backend is going to use a JWT token to find a user in a database.  The backend `/api/user` route will do the following:

1. Grab the JWT token from the HTTP `Authorization` header (which was populated by the Angular HttpInterceptor)
2. Verifies the JWT with a library such as `jsonwebtoken`
3. If JWT is valid, the `jsonwebtoken` library will decode it.  When you issued the token, you should have saved the user ID on the `sub` property of the JWT payload.  You can now use that `sub` property to retrieve the user from the database.
4. Return the retrieved user

Alright, so we can return to the original flow.  Remember, all of this was caused by the `GET_USER` action which had an effect that made a GET request to `/api/user`

5. At this point, you should have access to the user object in the effect.  You now will return another action such as `GET_USER_SUCCESS`, and pass the user object as an argument to this action.
6. `GET_USER_SUCCESS` will have a reducer that will set the authentication state of the application.  For example, you might set a property `isAuthenticated` to `true` and a property `user` to the user object attached to the `GET_USER_SUCCESS` action payload.

In summary, the fact that NgRx is clearing state on each refresh is by design.  Populating the user on page load is certainly not a simple process, but once implemented, you will have a predictable user authentication flow.

Comment: if every time i need to re-fetch data from server what is the meaning of store or state management????